# Laravel 4 - Seeding throwing errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if someone can help me.

I have a seed file which i have setup just like the documentation, when i run it though, im getting the following errors

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Plan' not found
```

My seed run function is as follows:

```
DB::table('plans')->delete();

Plan::create(

    array(
        'slug' => 'free',
        'planname' => 'Free',
    )

);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: does your Plan class exists in a namespace?

Comment: @seblaze - Hey, sorry im new to Laravel and not really sure what that means ... I just followed the instructions given on the laravel docs

Comment: where is your Plan class ? can you attach it ? all of it ?

Comment: I dont have any plan class ... I just created the migration file to create a Plans table, and then added the above code to the PlanTableSeeder.php file

Comment: You need to create a model named Plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As on your comment, the error seems to occur because you used the class Plan without creating the class Plan.

First you need to create a model named Plan.

Go to `app/models` folder then create a file named: `Plan.php`.

Inside `Plan.php` put:

```
<?php

class Plan extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'plans';
    protected $fillable = array('slug', 'planname');

}
```

the `$fillable` property accepts an array of column names on your table. This is to allow inserting of data and avoid mass assignment.

Then re-run your seed command.

For more info on Laravel models, go to the [eloquent docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response, please create a Plan model
[Here is how](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

You will also need to create a migration, based on how you want your plan to be.
[Here is how](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations)

After you run your migration, and you created your model, then you can create your seeder.

You will have something like this :

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Plan extends Eloquent  {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'plans';
...

}
```

Please keep in mind all properties needed for your model, so that your database seeds won't have any problems ( guarded properties, etc )

[Read here about a tutorial](http://laravelbook.com/laravel-database-seeding/)